# How to get weekly range

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to developing iOS apps and I am facing problem getting a weekly date range.

Basically, what I was trying to achieve is to get a list of items between a specified range of date between daily, weekly and monthly. Daily would be fixing the date whereas monthly just change the month. But I couldn't achieve weekly like from (7/12/14) which is a Sunday to (13/12/14) Saturday, and (14/12/14) Sunday to (20/12/14) Saturday where Sunday is the first weekday.

Comment: When you ask a question on Stack Overflow, we also expect you to show what you have tried so far, why that didn't work for you, perhaps also show other questions on the site that you found while searching for an answer (you did search before asking, right?) and explain why those answers didn't answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
let now = NSDate()
var startDate: NSDate? = nil
var duration: NSTimeInterval = 0

// or .DayCalendarUnit, .MonthCalendarUnit
NSCalendar.currentCalendar().rangeOfUnit(.WeekCalendarUnit, startDate: &startDate, interval: &duration, forDate: now);

let endDate = startDate?.dateByAddingTimeInterval(duration)
```